# Azure App Service with websockets and AD authentication

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-active-directory

we got an application deployed as App Service and we are using SignalR for communication. After enabling AAD authentication - in browsers we started receiving 302 responses with redirect location to Azure AD.

Seems like the authentication layer on App Service is ignoring `access_token` passed by query string.

Request

```
Request URL: wss://<url>/hubs/chat?access_token=<token>
Request Method: GET
```

Response

```
Status Code: 302 Redirect
Location: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?...
```

After looking everywhere we couldn't find any solution to make this work.
The only solution to this issue that we see is either to disable authentication on App Service or use Long-Pooling, but both options are not acceptable in our situation.

Comment: So I just created a .NET Core Web App that is using AAD to authenticate.  That said, I'm wondering what your implementation is.  Are you using .NET Core?  Also, is this an web API (assuming yes)?  Have you looked at this? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore.git  I can try to look into this for you tomorrow.

Comment: @Rogala the AAD works fine with the API calls (when the authorization token is passed in the header). Issue only happens when using SignalR (token is passed in query string)

Comment: It’s because the protocol requires it in the header.  The example below is in the right direction.  Another quick option, if you are going through a proxy (like Apigee), you could move it to the header.  I’ll try to replicate it tonight.

Comment: Not sure if proxy is acceptable in our solution, but I don't think so. The question is strictly about App Service with turned on authentication working with SignalR - a confirmation that it is not possible then that is an ok answer as well then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple calls with Microsoft Technical Support, MS confirmed that App Service Authentication layer doesn't support access token passed in query string and there are no plans for this support yet. So there are two options:

- Use different protocol for SignalR (long pooling works just fine)
- Drop App Service Authentication

Answer (score 0):

By default, you web application will not get the access token from query string. Commonly, it will get the access token from authorization header or the cookie.

To get the access token from query string, you need to implement your custom authentication   way.

1. Install Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory NuGet package.
2. Create an authentication provider which will get access token from query string.

`public class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        var value = context.Request.Query.Get("access_token");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            context.Token = value;
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}`

3. Add map in .

`app.Map("/yourpath", map =>
 {
     map.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
     {
         Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
         Tenant = tenantId,
         TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidAudience = clientId
         }
     });
     map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
 });`

Comment: Our applications supports query string authorization just fine, the issue is with the authentication on App Service rejects the request before it reaches our app.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom middleware, I was able to update the request prior to authorization occurring:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stackoverflow.Example.Security.Middleware
{
    public class BearerTokenFromQueryToHeaderMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public BearerTokenFromQueryToHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't try to get this working with the OpenID framework, but I did test using a custom policy.  As long as this is registered earlier than the authentication, then this middleware should execute prior to the framework looking for the token in the header.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as mentioned earlier we have a working solution in our code, but the problem is with Authentication AppService layer then the request never reaches our API.